# How to deal with an incompetent moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

Asked this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/1565766/difference-between-a-serial-and-a-usb-port

a few days back and it got closed because "Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

It's obvious that, from the user's contributions so far, he does not have the technical know-how to answer the question. As such, he shouldn't have any say in closing the question (or any other of the kind). Kindly, reopen it.

Comment: Downvotes? Stackexchange really went down the ...

Comment: Carrots tend to work better than sticks and resorting to insults reflects more poorly on you than anyone else. It would be better if you were discussing the technical reasons for why your question is actually on topic and whether you are correct in asking it here rather than immediately jumping to "this other person is wrong, they must be incompetent". Downvotes on meta represent the fact that people disagree with your question or point of view, in this case as your "point" is that someone is incompetent we can only infer that people do not believe this to be the case.

Comment: Removed user name from question as meta questions should not call out specific users.

Answer (score 7):

Well - it's rather presumptuous to assume incompetence.

A quick look at the question seems to indicate that the key parts of the question involve microcontrollers and information specific to them to answer. While there is a PC and a USB to serial bridge in play, they seem non relevant to the question. As such I don't see a real issue with the closure.

Make a case for it and explain why we're wrong, not attack the expertise of a community moderator.